# Printing out the mean value of the specific column

Tags: r

I have the following code in air which is aimed at doing the following: provide the mean of the column i specify of all .csv files in a directory

```
meanColumn <- function(directory, pol, id=1:2){
  getfiles <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  for(i in id) {
   print("hello") #just to check whether looping goes fine
   file<- read.csv(getfiles[i]) #store all results
   colPol <- file[, pol] #get the second column of the .csv file
   x <- mean(colPol) #get the mean of this column
 print(x) #print it :)
}
getfiles #just for checking
}
```

When I run this function like this meanColumn("Assignment1", 2) I get the following output however.

Any thoughts on where I go wrong?

Comment: What is the output you get and what is the expected result?

Comment: please edit your OP, I don't understand why you have `print("hello")` and `getfiles` at the end?? also the line `colPol <- file[, pol]` needs pol to be just one column in quotes, maybe you input the column-name incorrectly,

Comment: I would pull the files all in at once instead of one at a time. `fileslist <- read.csv(getfiles[id])` then something like `Map(mean, lapply(fileslist, '[[', i=pol))`

Comment: @SpaceghostAli, I edited my question. Hope its understandable now. Result is get now is "NA" while it should be a number...

Answer (score 0):

I already got the answer. I forgot to filter out the "NA" values. This works:

```
meanColumn <- function(directory, pol, id=1:2){
 getfiles <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
  for(i in id) {
   print("hello")
   file<- read.csv(getfiles[i])
   col_mean_with_NA <- file[, pol]
   colPol <- col_mean_with_NA[!is.na(col_mean_with_NA)] 
   x <- sum(colPol)
  print(x)
  }
 getfiles
}
```